# Unable to project subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document in MongoDB.

Actual output:

```
> db.test.findOne({},{_id:0,abc:1})
{ "abc" : "{ \"d\" : 4.864, \"t\" : 16, \"g\" : 5 }" }
```

I want to to bring the field `abc.d` up to the root but the following approaches do not work.

```
> db.test.aggregate([{$project:{"_id":0,"abc.d":1}}])

> db.test.aggregate([{$project:{"_id":0,abcd:"$abc.d"}}])
```

Does it have to do with the fact that there are additional quotes in the original subdocument?

Comment: I'm afraid the value of "abc" is not a 'sub-document', but just a string that contains JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your doc, `abc` is not a sub document. Putting the value of abc doc in quotes has made it like a json string and nothing else.

In order to store it as a sub-document, you need to store it like :

```
{ 
   "abc" : { 
     "d" : 4.864,
     "t" : 16,
     "g" : 5 
    }
}
```

Now, the below aggregation projection will work :

```
db.test.aggregate([{$project:{"_id":0,abcd:"$abc.d"}}])
```

Result :

```
{ "abcd" : 4.864 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this insight. These documents were actually exported from another mongo database which I do not have access to. Is there a way to project a Json string into a sub-document?